# claims missing using ASP.net core identity and itfoxtec with okta

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, okta, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I implemented the sample solution using .NET, Okta and ITFOXTEC found [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp).
Everything worked fine.  I then tried to integrate this solution into our main codebase which is also using ASP.NET Identity.  Once I added the identity configuration, it seems whatever identity that was created by ITFoxtec was overwritten (none of the SAML claims are present after login).
I reproduced the issue by adding the following to the Startup.cs in the sample solution above.

```
       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

       services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I'm hoping to use both SAML and Identity framework in the same solution, but not sure they are compatible.

Comment: Are you calling CreateClaimsPrincipal which fills the Entity Context with data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it this is possible, I have never tried it. However, I think it is possible.

It sounds like the received SAML 2.0 identity is overridden and thereby also the claims.
Please share your findings if you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but we have got SAML working with ASP.NET Identity in an ASP.NET MVC Core 6 application. We used the same [sample mentioned above](https://github.com/nickgamb/Okta_SAML_Example/blob/47d52f6e499b9445d852f93c8749bbf703bef468/Pages/ClaimsTransform.cs#L20) and did this in the `CreateClaimsPrincipal` method of the `ClaimsTransform` class:

```
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Claims;

    ...

    // add the ASP.NET Identity roles as Claims
    var idClaim = GetClaim(incomingPrincipal, Saml2ClaimTypes.NameId);
    if (idClaim != null)
    {
        IdentityUser identityUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(idClaim.Value);
        if (identityUser != null)
        {
            foreach (var r in await userManager.GetRolesAsync(identityUser))
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Role, value: r));
            }
        }
    }
```

We probably should make `ClaimsTransform` non static and inject the `UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager` but right now it's being passed in as a parameter from the call in `AuthController`.

After this normal ASP.NET Identity stuff worked. Authorize attributes on Controllers and Actions:
`[Authorize(Roles = "Identity Role 1, Identity Role 2")]`

And `User.IsInRole("Identity Role 1")` checks in code and .cshtml

And in `program.cs` we do the SAML configuration last - just before `var app = builder.Build();`

The only other thing that you might want to do is prevent access to some/all of the default Identity pages. We did this in `program.cs` to prevent users accessing the Registration page but you can also scaffold the identity pages and edit them [as Microsoft suggests here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003535#disable-a-page-1).

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{    
    endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/Register", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/", true, true)));
    endpoints.MapPost("/Identity/Account/Register", context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/", true, true)));
}
```